# Unable to establish a connection to Apache AGE server from Go application

Tags: database, go, apache-age

I'm working on a Go application that needs to connect to an Apache AGE server, but I'm encountering an issue when trying to establish the connection.

When I run my Go application and attempt to connect to the Apache AGE server, I'm getting a 'cannot connect to Apache Age server' error.

I'm using the following code to establish the connection from my Go application:

```
db, err := sql.Open("age", "host=localhost port=5432 dbname=mydb
user=myuser password=mypassword")if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer db.Close()
```

I expected the code to successfully establish a connection to the Apache AGE server, allowing me to perform database operations.

However, when running the code, I'm getting a 'cannot connect to Apache AGE server' error. I have confirmed that the Apache AGE server is running and accepting connections on the specified host and port.

Answer (score 1):

```golang
package main

import (
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

var dsn string = "host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 dbname=postgres user=postgres password=agens sslmode=disable"

func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", dsn)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // ...
}
```

See [the official sample](https://github.com/apache/age/tree/42f94e7f36dc084b74ec335536a18173c6fca4cd/drivers/golang/samples) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Check the PostgreSQL driver. GO typically use a PostgreSQL driver like **pq** or **pgx** to connect to an Apache AGE server. Please ensure you have imported the correct driver in your code.